# Java client does not connect when bypassing proxy to corporate network

Tags: proxy, java

I am on a Windows 7 client that connects to a corporate network. We are running Pentaho Data Integration  Client on the client that connects to a Pentaho DI Server that is on the corperate network.

When we don't set any proxy parameters in IE we can make a connection from the Pentaho Java Client to the Pentaho Server, but not to the internet.

When we set a proxy in IE with proxy exceptions for the Pentaho DI server we can get on the internet and reach the Pentaho DI server from the browser. The Pentaho DI Client however pops up with a proxy authorization dialog. Whatever we try for credentials there (including domains in the form DOMAIN\User and User@DOMAIN) we cannot get through the proxy.

How can we get on the internet as well as proxy?

Comment: Work with your internal network and/or systems teams.

Comment: Solved. When working with FQDN proxy exceptions instead of servernames it works! No idea why!?